# Magento promotions setup: How to give a free product with an online order?

Tags: discount, promotions, setup

How to set up the Magento promotion to be able to give away a free product that is different than the one purchased. in other words, the promotion is not type BOGO FREE. It's the following:
Purchase a product A with 20% off and receive bonus: free deluxe sample of product D.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link work for you
http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide-Jan-29/content/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html

http://blog.goods-pro.com/1733/magento-extension-buy-x-selection-of-products-get-another-y-selection-for-free/